# Displaying multiple Child under Parent (Preference) in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to achieve something related to this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/3vqyo8xlx5

But I want the child to appear under the preference of where the button of "Add Child" is clicked, not on the last one.

Please, I need help on this

Comment: Consider making your code more modular. Have different child component and a different subchild component and have the child be responsible for rendering its own subchildren. That way you can structure a hierarchy. Also consider providing the code in the question itself as a question needs to be self-sufficient and not require 3rd party links to be fully understood

Answer (score 0):

Is this your code? Look the way it's designed, you're using one array to store parents and other to store it's children. Instead, why don't you create an array of objects in the state, then add a new object when you input preferences, add the preferences as values of each object, then just render them using array map (one for objects and one nested map to get the values of each parameter).